# Tab-based navigation routing difficulties

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have an tab based app with login that previously had the login as a modal over the tabview. However on loading, the tabview was briefly visible before the login was overlaid which we did not want.

So have restructured the app according to this article [Implementing a Login for NativeScript Apps with Tab-based Navigation](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation) and associated [demo](https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng) using ‘Nested Aux Page Outlets’ and a lazy loaded module for the tabs page.

I can't figure out how to create links from the content area of one tab to another tab.

In my home component template I have a link

```
<Label row="0"  text="Expense"  class="homeItemTitle"  [nsRouterLink]="['../expense']"></Label>
```

The location of the expense component is defined in expense.module.ts

```
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild([
            { path: "", redirectTo: "expense" },
            { path: "expense", component: ExpenseComponent },
            { path: "expense/:claimid", component: ReceiptComponent},           
        ])
```

And the location of expense.module.ts is defined in tab.module.ts

```
            {
                path: "default", component: TabsComponent, children: [
                    {
                        path: "home",
                        outlet: "homeTab",
                        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                        loadChildren: () => import("~/home/home.module").then(m => m.HomeModule),
                    },
                    {
                        path: "expense",
                        outlet: "expenseTab",
                        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                        loadChildren: () => import("~/expense/expense.module").then(m => m.ExpenseModule),
                    },
                    {
                        path: "journey",
                        outlet: "journeyTab",
                        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                        loadChildren: () => import("~/journey/journey.module").then(m => m.JourneyModule),
                    },
                    {
                        path: "reports",
                        outlet: "reportsTab",
                        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                        loadChildren: () => import("~/reports/reports.module").then(m => m.ReportsModule),
                    }
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
```

When I tap the link I get the error message

```
JS: ### ErrorHandler Error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/default'
JS: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/default'
```

I then tried the following:

Link in home component template:

```
<Label row="0"  text="Expense"  class="homeItemTitle" (tap)="navigateToExpense()"></Label>
```

```
    navigateToExpense() {
        this.routerExt.navigate([
            '../expense', { outlets: { expenseTab: ['expense'] } }
        ])
    } 

Which yields the error
```

JS: ### ErrorHandler Error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'expense'
JS: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'expense'

```
Any ideas what I am missing here?

TIA
```

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NgModuleFactoryLoader, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, ErrorHandler, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";
import { NSModuleFactoryLoader } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { AppRoutingModule, COMPONENTS } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { CoreModule } from "./core/core.module";
//import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";

import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";


import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";

import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from "nativescript-angular/http-client";

import { DropDownModule } from "nativescript-drop-down/angular";
//import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";
import { ModalDialogService } from "nativescript-angular/modal-dialog";
import { ModalService } from './login/modal.service';
import { PasswordModalService } from './forgot_password/modal.service';
import { ModalDatePickerComponent } from "./modal-datepicker/modal-datepicker.component";
import { MinLengthDirective, IsEmailDirective, IsNumberDirective } from "./input.directive";
import { ReportsComponent } from "~/reports/reports.component";
import { UpdateService } from "~/shared/update.service";
import { UtilsService } from "~/shared/utils.service";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import { FRouteService } from './routeService';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { enable as traceEnable, addCategories } from "tns-core-modules/trace";

traceEnable();

export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error) {
        console.log("### ErrorHandler Error: " + error.toString());
        console.log("### ErrorHandler Stack: " + error.stack);
    }
}


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
//        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptUIListViewModule,

        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        NativeScriptHttpModule,
        NativeScriptHttpClientModule,
        DropDownModule,        
//        NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
        CoreModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ModalDatePickerComponent,
        MinLengthDirective,
        IsEmailDirective,
        IsNumberDirective,
        ...COMPONENTS
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ],
    providers: [
        ModalDialogService,
        ModalService,
        PasswordModalService,
        ReportsComponent,
        UpdateService,
        FRouteService,
        UtilsService,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler },
        { provide: NgModuleFactoryLoader, useClass: NSModuleFactoryLoader }
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ModalDatePickerComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And these are the routes in app-routing.module.ts:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [

    { path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },

    {
        path: "tabs",
        loadChildren: () => import("~/tabs/tabs.module").then(m => m.TabsModule)
    },
```

=========
May 28th adding tabs.component.html

```
<BottomNavigation>
    <TabStrip iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal">

        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="Home"></Label>
            <Image src="font://&#xf007;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="Expense"></Label>
            <Image src="font://&#xf0c0;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="Journey"></Label>
            <Image src="font://&#xf007;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="Reports"></Label>
            <Image src="font://&#xf007;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>                 

    </TabStrip>

    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="homeTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>

    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="expenseTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>

    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="journeyTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>

    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="reportsTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>


</BottomNavigation>
```

I have the routing function in a service FRouteService and I am importing this into the component with the link to another tab.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { BottomNavigation } from "tns-core-modules/ui/bottom-navigation";

@Injectable()
export class FRouteService {

  constructor(
    private bottomNav: BottomNavigation) {}

  routeto(index) {
    this.bottomNav.selectedIndex=index;
  }
}
```

When I load the app I get the following error.

```
JS: ### ErrorHandler Error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FRouteService -> BottomNavigation]:
JS:   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FRouteService -> BottomNavigation]:
JS:     NullInjectorError: No provider for BottomNavigation!
JS: Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for BottomNavigation!
JS:     at NullInjector.push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:1225:0) [angular]
JS:     at resolveToken (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:1463:0) [angular]
JS:     at tryResolveToken (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:1407:0) [angular]
JS:     at StaticInjector.push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:1311:0) [angular]
JS:     at resolveToken (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:1463:0) [angular]
JS:     at tryResolveToken (file:///data/data/com.FileEx...
JS: ### ErrorHandler Stack: Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FRouteService -> BottomNavigation]:
JS:   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FRouteService -> BottomNavigation]:
JS:     NullInjectorError: No provider for BottomNavigation!
JS: Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for BottomNavigation!
JS:     at NullInjector.push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:1225:0) [angular]
JS:     at resolveToken (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:1463:0) [angular]
JS:     at tryResolveToken (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:1407:0) [angular]
JS:     at StaticInjector.push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:1311:0) [angular]
JS:     at resolveToken (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:1463:0) [angular]
JS:     at tryResolveToken (file:///data/data/com.FileEx...
```

Am I going about navigating the BottomLoader the right way?

I don't understand the message

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for BottomNavigation!
```

Comment: Do you have a tabs routing module? Thats in there?

Comment: Hi Manoj. There is no tabs.module.ts. I have pasted my app.module.ts at the foot of my original post.

Comment: Hi Manoj, apologies my typo. What do you mean by tabs routing module? I think the tab routes are defined in tabs.module.ts no? I'm still not cracking this. Any idea how I can route from the content area of, say, home.component.html to another tab eg expense.component.html. Thanks.

Comment: You can not change tab index from router, use selected index attribute on tab.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj We previously used the original Tab based navigation template and we used the following to change tab index (I think you suggested this to me) 
````(<TabView> app.getRootView()).selectedIndex=index;```` 
However this no longer works. I do not get errors in the console, just that the the tab index does not change. Any ideas? Thx

Comment: I should have clarified, we are using BottomNavigation and TabStrip/TabStripItem/TabContentItem. I have added my tabs.component.html to my OP and my try at changing the selectedIndex with error message

Comment: BottomNavigation also supports selectedIndex, it is not a component / directive so I don't think you can use dependency injection and you can already notice the static injector error. Access it by ViewChild in its original component and use a service to set / get index.

Comment: Got it working the way you suggested - thanks @Manoj!